# Python : How to find the count of empty cells in one column based on another column element wise?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice','Jane', 'Alice','Bob', 'Alice'], 
               'income': [40000, np.nan, 42000, 50000, np.nan, np.nan, 30000]})

    user   income
0    Bob  40000.0
1   Jane      NaN
2  Alice  42000.0
3   Jane  50000.0
4  Alice      NaN
5    Bob      NaN
6  Alice  30000.0
```

I want to find the count of all the Null Values in 'income' column based on 'user' column in my df ?
I'm trying something like this: `len(df[df.income.isnull().sum()])` but it is incomplete.

Comment: Please provide the current and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`pdcrosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['income'].isnull())[True].sort_values(ascending = False)
#user
#Alice    1
#Bob      1
#Jane     1
#Name: True, dtype: int64
```

or [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
df['income'].isnull().groupby(df['user']).sum().astype(int).sort_values(ascending=False)
#user
#Alice    1
#Bob      1
#Jane     1
#Name: income, dtype: int64
```

**Note**

I have used astype here because if the count is 1 it will return `True`

Comment: can we also sort the count in descending order ?

Comment: yes, use `sort_values(ascending = False)` at the end, see the update solution. Consider accept the answer if it is correct:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `value_counts()`:

```
df.loc[df['income'].isna(), 'user'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Jane     1
Bob      1
Alice    1
Name: user, dtype: int64
```